# Identifier 'email' is not defined and element reference do not contain such member

Tags: angular

I am creating a form and i use reactive form vallidation. it always give me following error. i don't know what is going wrong

Here is the error

```
{
"resource": "/d:/angular/my-app/src/app/admin/login/login.component.html",
"owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#1",
"severity": 8,
"message": "Identifier 'email' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a member",
"source": "Angular",
"startLineNumber": 88,
"startColumn": 29,
"endLineNumber": 88,
"endColumn": 34
}
```

Here is the code
[image]
[image]

Any solution appreciated!

Comment: Looking at https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms (and the Live Example linked from that page - the profile editor component), the FormGroup is initialised directly as a class member rather than in an ngOnInit - could you try that ?    Also, please NEVER post screenshots of code !!  Rather, always post code as code-formatted text.  A major part of trying to help is replicating the problem - best performed  by copy and pasting.  Putting an image up stops us from doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is likely to declare an email variable in your component.

```
email: AbstractControl

ngOnInit() {
  this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
    email: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    password: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
  });
  this.email = this.loginForm.controls.email;
}
```